# Best Practices: What's the preferred terminology for CRUD operations?

Tags: api, rest, crud

I'm creating an API that will mostly be used internally- but I'm going to create it in such a way that creating a RESTful interface in the future will be easy. I've been obsessing over all the tiny details, and I have everything nailed down, except the exact method naming for basic crud operations. As I see it, I have several options:

1. Create, Add, New, Post
2. Read, Get
3. Update, Edit, Put
4. Delete, Remove

There's probably more...

I'm leaning towards "add, get, edit, delete". The RESTful interface will be secondary to the internal API, so naming them along with the corresponding HTTP methods probably doesn't make too much sense (Standard Dev: "Why is the edit method called 'put'?? Who designed this anyways??").

And I'm well aware that there are far more important things in life! ;)

Comment: PUT really maps to replace better than edit.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using the HTTP Method names, I find that in the end its easier for other developers to read.

This strategy is also the default one in ASP.Net MVC4 Web API:

```
public class SomeRestController : ApiController 
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity> Get() { ... }

    public Entity Get(int id) { ... }

    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Entity e) { ... }

    public void Put(int id, Company c)  { ... }

    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id) { ... }
}
```

However, if the application that you are designing is completely detached from the API probably you should name the methods as collection-like (get, add, remove, etc.)